# Retrieving Customer Id, Name and systemsIds using JPA query

Tags: jpa

I have 2 entity classes like the one below.

I need to write JPAql so that  for each Customer I can get the id, name and all the systemIds.

I am very new at both this community and the technology jpa/hibernate, so I  don't know how to ask questions.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames ="name"))
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private int id;



    @Column(name = "name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age", nullable=false)
    private String age;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<String> systemIds;
}
```

Comment: Please note only 1 entity class  i have

Comment: Hello and welcome. You should start by reading this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I also suggest your read http://stackoverflow.com/help before creating any topics, as it will save you a lot of trouble.